# How do Windows Paths and Anaconda virtual environments work together?

Tags: python, anaconda

I started my Python journey a month ago by following a guide which recommended installing Anaconda. Since then I've written/adapted some Jupyter Notebooks using VS Code and run them from within virtual environments. Recently I needed to run one of these Notebooks via from MS Access VBA and got to understand a little about using Python from the command line - specifically about using Environment Variable Path functionality in Windows to access `Anaconda\Scripts` and use things like `activate` to active virtual environments.

In the video guide it also recommended adding `Anaconda3` to my Path so I could access `python.exe`. However, I've held off doing this because even after plenty of reading I'm still not clear on exactly the mechanics of of using this command when working with Anaconda virtual environments.

So to my question... say I add the `Anaconda3` folder to my Path and then write something like `python myscript.py` presumably it runs the `python.exe` interpreter from the `Anaconda3` folder? How will this work if I'm in a virtual environment that needs Python 3.7 but the interpreter I've loaded is actually Python 3.6? Does this even matter?

Please be assured I've read for a couple of hours on this before posting my question. Happy to read more if there is a **layperson** guide someone can point me towards. I've read through the Anaconda site.

Comment: to run your script using your virtual environment, you first need to activate that environment, in cmd run command `activate <env name>` then do `python myscript`, plus you can add custom env path to your notebook, which it automatically detect as python and it will run with that virtual env python

Comment: 1. I am pretty sure that adding anaconda to path will make anaconda python, the default python of your system (yes to first question). 2. If it is a conda environment I guess it will not be affected, after all that is why one installs conda. 3. Yes, adding anaconda to your path matters! As [Anaconda FAQ](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/) states "When installing Anaconda, we recommend that you do not add Anaconda to the Windows PATH because this can interfere with other software"

Comment: About tour second question no idea what will happen with python virtual enviroments not belonging to conda.

Comment: Thanks all. @Phineas - if you should add python to your path why do you think I see so many guides where the instructor types ```python myscript.py```?

Comment: @sahasrara62 - are you saying that if I do ```python myscript``` then it will run the python from my virtual environment? Also - what do you mean by "add custom env path to your notebook, which it automatically detect as python and it will run with that virtual env python"? Are you saying I add some code to my notebook to switch my environment?

Comment: @Jossy run your jupter notebook, and over there  you will find a option to set your python environment, i am suggesting click on that option and add the virtual env path over there to run you jupyter notebook with the virtual pytho environment

Comment: @sahasrara62 - that doesn't really help me from the command line! What I'm taking from the comments is that typing ```python myscript``` is bad. I should always activate the virtual environment and then call the python interpreter from the virtual environment directory

Comment: I think you got it wrong. Running `python somefile.py` is not wrong. However it depends on what your system understands when you type `python`. If Anaconda is in PATH, your system will use anaconda's python. If not it will use the system's python if any of the python version you have installed and added on path yourself. (Ubuntu and other linux have Python installed by default windows don't)

Comment: @Jossy for that first create a virtual env by using [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) in your project, then go into virtual env directory and run acrivate command and then you can use python somefile.py